# UIViewController view not size correctly when running iOS7 simulator

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a custom UIViewController which create a view containing an action bar at the top (view with 4 buttons), a tableview and then another view below the tableview. Layout is done all in code and is not using auto layout.
Everything works perfectly on various device with iOS 7.0 and 7.0.2, but in the simulator, the root view of the controller get anchored at the top right corner of the screen (0,0) instead of below the navigation bar.

I'm going to force the relay out in the viewDidAppear: method, but this seem like a hack...

Thanks for any insights

[image]
Edit: added an image. You can see the UIView highlighted. As ManicMonkOnMac mentioned, the UIView is under the toolbar (but this only happens in the simulator, on the device, the view lines up fine)
In the loadView method on the controller, i set the frame when creating the view:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    // Our parent view controller will resize us appropriately. The size set
    // here is a convenience for initial view layout.
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
}
```

But this frame is later changed. Not by my code, though, but by UIkit code)

Edit2: addded loadView method body

Comment: screenshot will be better to understand this problem

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: After going through session 201 of WWDC 2013, I think I have the solution.**

in iOS 7 there is a property that you can set on your view controllers to specify whether you want the views to be overlapped by navigation bar.

```
viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;//UIRectEdgeAll specifies that nav bars should overlap the view.
```

Unlike iOS 6, navigation bars are placed over the views in iOS 7.

Use the frame size that excludes the navigation bar.

code:

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,self.view.frame.origin.y+self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);

CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[self.view addSubview: view];

Comment: But why would it work on the device, but not the simulator? Also, how do i get the frame size that exclude the navigation bar? and right now i'm not setting the size of the view in code, it is set automatically by the window

Comment: in response to your edit, just use the method mentioned above to load the view instead of the view controller.

Comment: Sorry, i''m not sure which method above you refer to, or what you mean by loading the view instead of the controller given that i instanciate a view from scratch. THanks for your help

Comment: I have changed the code above to load the view, when you instantiate your view just use the custom frame derived above.

Comment: Makes sense. Two issues i see with the proposed solution. 1: If i do this, i'll have to add conditional code to detect iOS 7 on simulator as this is the only place where this fails. 2: i'm already doing this and the size get changed by UIKit later in the execution.

Comment: Hi, I was going through the WWDC 2013 sessions and I think I have found the solution. I have edited the answer.